# How to define the correct startup order of a Java Tomcat application?

Tags: java, tomcat, web.xml

In my Java Tomcat application I setup some properties to be used in the whole application. But apparently other functions (eg Hibernate) are already starting before and need some of these properties.

The properties are initialized in the class defined in web.xml with:

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>com.mycode.ApplicationContextListener</listener-class
</listener>
```

Is there a way (in web.xml?) to define the very first function to be started when Tomcat starts the application? Or another method?

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: How do you start Hibernate etc? Are you using Spring?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the XML tag "loadOnStartup" as described [here](http://crunchify.com/how-to-run-java-program-automatically-on-tomcat-startup/), to define which class has to startup first.

Answer (score 2):

In my understanding you have some properties you want to access/reference from some loaded classes before your Servlet context is initialised.

1. In case this is some 3rd party library like Hibernate then they have
   their own properties file to use for the reason.
2. You can use Tomcat's properties during Tomcat init before any 3rd party     libraries loaded into the JVM used by Tomcat.
3. The standard Java Properties file
   that is loaded in the JVM during class path init before invoking any Java application from the JVM.

Comment: reorganized some dependencies and used the "loadOnStartup" as Sam suggested, and problem solved within an hour! Oh I love stackoverflow ;-)